# Find and Replace a String usng a Json Key Value pair object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, replace, key-value, mysql-json

I'm having a MySQL **database table** namely `ds_message`, it contains the template and JSON object. I would like to find the Key which is present in the template string with the JSON Key and replace the key with the JSON Value.

Table:

```
_____________________________________________________________________________________
id  template                                  key_value
_____________________________________________________________________________________
1  'Dear {a}, the price of {b} is {c}'       '{"a":"John", "b":"bat", "c":"$10"}'
2  'Dear {i}, you selected the product {j}'  '{"i":"Emma", "j":"Jam"}'
```

I need the SQL Select statement to get the string `Dear John, the price of bat is $10` and each template have N number of keys, its not an identical across the table.

***Table Structure:***

```
CREATE TABLE `ds_message` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `template` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `key_value` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='';

ALTER TABLE `ds_message`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

INSERT INTO `ds_message` (`id`, `template`, `key_value`) VALUES
(1, 'Dear {a}, the price of {b} is {c}', '{"a":"John", "b":"bat", "c":"$10"}');

INSERT INTO `ds_message` (`id`, `template`, `key_value`) VALUES
(2, 'Dear {i}, you selected the product {j}', '{"i":"Emma", "j":"Jam"}');
```

***Expected Result:***

1. Dear John, the price of bat is $10
2. Dear Emma, you selected the product Jam

Kindly assist me in SELECT statement or by Stored Procedure.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - MySQL 5.7 as well as 8

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, using JSON path expressions along with the `REPLACE` function:

```
WITH ds_message AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'Dear {a}, the price of {b} is {c}' AS template, '{"a":"John", "b":"bat", "c":"$10"}'AS key_value
)

SELECT
    id,
    template,
    key_value,
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(template, '{c}', key_value->"$.c"),
                '{b}', key_value->"$.b"),
                    '{a}', key_value->"$.a") AS output
FROM ds_message;
```

This outputs the following for `output`:

```
Dear "John", the price of "bat" is "$10"
```

Comment: The problem I'm facing here is, the the key value will be anything its not consistent for all the records, one record may have x,y,z and another may have j,k.... I up-voted for your effort. could you please assist me.

Comment: Then MySQL is not the best place to be doing these replacements.

Comment: I modified the question in a clear way - Update version.

Comment: I don't' think you can do what you want without using dynamic SQL (e.g. in a stored procedure).

Comment: No issues... Could you please share your idea through stored procedure, I too trying the same.

Comment: I posted one more question related to this JSON, could you please assist me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586827/how-to-store-a-key-and-value-in-a-table-from-a-json-object-in-mysql