# How to store a key and value in a table from a JSON object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, key-value, mysql-json

I'm having a MySQL database tables namely ds_message and ds_params, it table ds_message contains a JSON object in each row. I would like to store the key and value of a JSON object into the table ds_params for all the records by referring the ds_message primary key `id`

Table: ds_message

```
_____________________________________________________________________________________
id  key_value
_____________________________________________________________________________________
1  '{"a":"John", "b":"bat", "c":"$10"}'
2  '{"i":"Emma", "j":"Jam"}'
```

I'm required to insert the key_value into another table like

```
_________________________________________________
id   message_id    json_key    json_value
_________________________________________________
1    1             'a'         'John'
2    1             'b'         'bat'
3    1             'c'         '$10'
4    2             'i'         'Emma'
5    2             'j'         'Jam'
```

***Table Structure:***

```
CREATE TABLE `ds_message` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `key_value` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='';

ALTER TABLE `ds_message`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

INSERT INTO `ds_message` (`id`, `key_value`) VALUES
(1, '{"a":"John", "b":"bat", "c":"$10"}');

INSERT INTO `ds_message` (`id`, `key_value`) VALUES
(2, '{"i":"Emma", "j":"Jam"}');

CREATE TABLE `ds_params` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `message_id` int NOT NULL,
  `json_key` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `json_value` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='';

ALTER TABLE `ds_params`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Kindly assist me how to achieve this, it may be a simple select cum insert statement or by stored procedure in an optimized way.

Comment: You need to split the JSON and insert one by one programmatically on the backend. You are using PHP as backend?

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria I'm using Java as a back-end, but I required the solution in MySQL not in Java.

Comment: could this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137915/how-can-write-queries-in-mysql-that-can-parse-json-data-in-a-column

Answer (score 0):

Use [MySql JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html) functions. The following information will help you writing a stored procedure which fills the table `key_value` from `ds_message`.

1. To get the key array of your object, use `json_keys`

   ```
    SELECT JSON_keys('{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}')
   ```
2. You can get the value of each property using a key

   ```
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}', '$.foo');
   ```
3. Use a nested loop to iterate the `ds_message` records and iterate each json object using the above methods. Insert a record for each key in each object.